# Zero Copy with databases

Tags: database, oracle, linux-kernel

Is it possible to perform a zero copy between a database (preferably oracle) and a socket?
Zero Copy : http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6345

Comment: Driteknight we request you to try it yourself and in case of any issues faced then please get the help from us. Please note that this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do, hence not sure the question makes any sense.

Comment: As you can see mmap can be used to share the kernel and user buffer. Is it possible to apply the same with databases? Because according to my understanding when you make a read call from database, the data is available to the code in user space... What is need is to avoid those extra copies between kernel space to user space and back to kernel space for network transmission

Comment: @vimal I couldn't find any alternative to mmap for databases. Hence I asked if zero copy itself is possible between databases and a network socket.